# How to handle `get request` with long parameters in Angular httpClient?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-httpclient

Here is my scenario, in the front end user can see the student result by sending their student id to back-end. I am using get method to pass those student id's to back-end. i am getting result of students and it works well.

But Now i am finding an error as:

"`The resource you looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is Temporarily unavailable`" in the browser.

I find this, whenever the user selects more that 200+ student ids and angular trying to send them using `get method`. I find that, there is a limitation like 2000 characters to use in get method.

But in this case how to `HttpClient` handles this? is there any workaround we have with angular? or what is the general practice?

In case of enterprise application how they send large values to backed using `get` method?

I am not able to find any solution myself with this. any one help me please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum length of HTTP GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Comment: @mbojko - I understood that, I am looking for work-around or angular facilities which can help here

Comment: A simple one would be to send two or more requests with shorter URI. Or change the API and send the ids in the request body.

Comment: @mbojko - how to send the values in request body in case of `get` method?

Comment: You can't. You need to change the method of the request. The method "POST" is what you need.

Comment: @DamienRoelens - I approached that, client is not agree.

Comment: In that case I agree with the suggestion of @mbojko...